# Angular duplicate imports in sub-modules

Tags: angular, module

In Angular 7 or 8 is there an issue if module(s) are imported into a module and than also imported with another module that may already include the same module(s)?

In other words, suppose we have a module 'ModuleA' and 'ModuleB'.
Some sections of our project use 'ModuleA', other sections use 'ModuleB'.
We also have 'ModuleC' that imports 'ModuleA'.
Now we have  'ModuleD' that imports 'ModuleA' and also imports 'ModuleC'.

We know that 'ModuleC' already has 'ModuleA', but the programmer missed that.

What will Angular do? Import 'ModuleA' 1x or 2x? Will there be issues? What kind of issues?

Comment: better to create **SharedModule** and add all the shared component in the SharedModule. Import this module wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Angular, there is no problem with doing so:

Take this scenario:

You create a custom form control, wrapped in a component, using the `ReactiveFormsModule` as Angular Material does for example.
You create a module which imports the `ReactiveFormsModule` and export the component, we'll call it `CutsomControlModule`.

You want to to use your custom control in another application, so you first importing the `CutsomControlModule` in you `AppModule` and then also importing the `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `AppModule`, cause you actually want to create your form.

This is really common scenario in Angular application, and there is no problem with doing so.

P.S - With Ivy, things going to be a bit different since you can create this component and just use the `renderComponent` function without wrapping it in a module.